# Find Nth occurrence of date in data using regex

Tags: regex

I want to be able to find out the first and second date from the following data.

```
10/26/2014

            4
            4
            9

10/27/2014

            1
            2
            1
```

Is it possible to find out the first date and second date with regex (no additionally programming - I use VB.Net)?

Comment: why don't you match the 4,4,9 too?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get as your output if you want to identify both dates but state `"your regex would not work as it will return both dates"`

Comment: You say "morning" and "evening", but they look like two completely different days to me. Anyway, you need to edit your question as it makes no sense as it stands.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. The data is for example. The problem here is limited to identifying dates only. I want to be able to identify first date and second date separately.

Comment: I am using .Net, but I am interested in knowing if I can solve this problem with no additional programming in .Net. If regex can do it, I would only use regex for it.

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
\d*\/\d*\/\d*[\r\n\s]*(\d)[\r\n\s]*(\d)[\r\n\s]*(\d)
```

http://regex101.com/r/cW8qP8/1

Comment: No. It returns me everything (all numbers)! I want to identify the first date and second date separately using regex.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean then. You can plug in any number you want in the last three \d.